# Windows Phone 8 authentication with client certificate

Tags: authentication, windows-phone-8, client-certificates

Does Windows Phone 8 OS and it's API supports client authentication using certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can set a x501 certificate so the API kinda supports it, but I haven't been able to find a way to pick a cert. So it's like half of the API for this is there.

Answer (score 0):

No Windows Phone 8 sdk does not support client certificate. Please see [MSDN LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402533#BKMK_SecureSocketsLayerSSLcertificates) for more details.